# Python does not import seaborn-package, although installed

Tags: python, anaconda

I've installed the package using `conda install seaborn` in my terminal. This stated that the package was already installed.

When I try to import Seaborn into my editor (I'm using Canopy) and run a simple program, I am met with the following error:

> ImportError: No module named seaborn.

What is the reason for this and how can I solve it?

Comment: Probably canopy is using some other interpreter (not the anaconda one; check the paths).

Comment: It's not only you. I've been facing this for quite a while particularly with the jupyter notebook. @sascha no i don't think so; conda installs in the currently activated environment.

Comment: Do you get any error, for example when importing pyplot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this!! Include this in your code and wait for package to be downloaded.
I was pretty tired of not being able to download and install a new package and this worked for me-

```
import pip
pip.main(['install','seaborn'])
```

I got to know this from a youtube video-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ExwdL770ZM

It works like a charm for me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about conda but it probably installed Seaborn in a directory other than Python's directory. Try installing it with pip instead.

`pip install Seaborn`

Comment: I'm still fairly new to programming, does canopy use a different directory? Not entirely sure I understand what's going on.

Comment: Well, we're in the same boat atm because I've never used canopy or Seaborn or conda.

Answer (score 2):

try using

```
pip3 install seaborn
```

I had the same issue, I'm using Rodeo. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your anaconda-based installation of Python is not the same as the one Canopy uses. Try using Canopy's package manager:

```
enpkg seaborn
```